# xcode coordinates in lansdscape mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, coordinates, landscape

I have made a game in portrait mode but I want to do it in landscape mode and now all the coordinates have changed cause of the x an y. Can I have an image or something that could tell me where is the x and the y in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you pass from Portrait to Landscape? Did you rotate your view?

It is better to change it's frame and not rotate it, that way you won't obligated to switch coordinates or do other complex manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

X still runs horizontal, whether in P or L modes.

Comment: sounds like he rotated the view by PI/2 :)